# I'm having trouble with Google homepage, search results, Google Images. They are being showed in a very unusual way. What's the reason behind this?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

All the things mentioned above are working fine in Firefox but I'm having problem in Google Chrome. I'm posting below the screenshots of both the browsers displaying the same pages differently.

Firefox :

As I said, everything is normal in Firefox.

[image]

Google Chrome :

All the images are being displayed in a weird way. When I click on an image, it redirects me to the page hosting the image , instead of zooming it. Also this error is displaying in the console.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsF8q.png]
All other sites are working just fine on Chrome. Google homepage, images and search results are the places I've encountered problems on.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in chrome?

Comment: I tried disabling all the extensions but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I was the one who asked that question too, but it was on stackoverflow and someone migrated it to superuser. But I haven't been able to find a solution on either of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are viewing the Basic version of the Image page.  Simply remove the "&sout=1" from the URL and it should go back to the standard version.

Comment: Sorry, but I 'm not able to find "&sout=1". Can you point it out to me?